# Criar Trigger / Stored Procedure Mysql para alterar características de uma coluna

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tou tentando criar uma Trigger/Stored Function para quando o usuario alterar o valor de uma coluna de 0 para 1 ele mude a característica de outra coluna

```
CREATE TABLE `aluno` (
  `CPF_ALU` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `PRIORIDADE` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `CURSO` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `ANO_ENTRADA` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `SEMESTRE_ENTRADA` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `TURNO` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `MONITOR` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `VOLUNTARIO` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `BOLSISTA` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `DESISTIU` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `MEDIA_GERAL` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `PROJETO_C_BOLSA` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VALOR_BOLSA` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `ORIENTADOR_TCC` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CPF_ALU`),
  KEY `fk_curso_aluno_idx` (`CURSO`),
  KEY `fk_orientador_tcc_idx` (`ORIENTADOR_TCC`),
  KEY `fk_projeto_c_bolsa_idx` (`PROJETO_C_BOLSA`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cpf_aluno` FOREIGN KEY (`CPF_ALU`) REFERENCES `pessoa` (`CPF_P`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_curso_aluno` FOREIGN KEY (`CURSO`) REFERENCES `curso` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_orientador_tcc` FOREIGN KEY (`ORIENTADOR_TCC`) REFERENCES `professor` (`CPF_PROF`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_projeto_c_bolsa` FOREIGN KEY (`PROJETO_C_BOLSA`) REFERENCES `projeto` (`CODIGO`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Esse o script da tabela aluno, no caso quando o usuario setasse o valor da coluna bolsista para 1 (true) ele mudaria as `PROJETO_C_BOLSA` e `VALOR_BOLSA` para `NOT NULL`.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE alterarAluno ()
BEGIN
    START transaction;
        ALTER TABLE deinfo.aluno 
        CHANGE COLUMN PROJETO_C_BOLSA PROJETO_C_BOLSA INT(4) NOT NULL ,
        CHANGE COLUMN VALOR_BOLSA VALOR_BOLSA FLOAT NOT NULL ;
    COMMIT;
END $$
DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER $$
CREATE trigger configurarAlunoBolsistaInsert
before insert on deinfo.aluno for each row
begin
    if (new.bolsista = 1) then
        CALL deinfo.alterarAluno();
    end if;

end $$

DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE trigger configurarAlunoBolsistaUpdate
before update on aluno for each row
begin
    if (new.bolsista = 1) then
        CALL deinfo.alterarAluno();
    end if;

end $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Criei essas Triggers/Procedure para fazer com que funcionasse porém quando tento atualizar uma linha da tabela aluno ele me retorna esse erro:

```
UPDATE `aluno` SET `BOLSISTA`='1', `PROJETO_C_BOLSA`='1', `VALOR_BOLSA`='400' WHERE `CPF_ALU`='14114631887' 1422: Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda.

Estou usando MySQL57, já li a documentação mas não achei nada que pudesse me ajudar nesse sentido.

Comment: No lugar de CALL deinfo.alterarAluno(); faça o SET da coluna na própria trigger , além disto a sp alterarAluno chama a própria trigger o que pode gerar uma chamada recursiva

Comment: Não funciona também, mas eu arrumei de outra forma de fazer fiz a verificação na trigger e caso não estivesse preenchida retorna uma exceção para a aplicação e ela trata o erro.

Comment: Não há razão de projeto para alterar o tipo de uma coluna para toda a tabela em função da alteração de um registro único.